# How do i turn a list of data frames into time series objects that i can use with the x-13 seasonal package?

Tags: r, time-series, lapply

I have read in a multitude of series that i need to run x-13 on using the following:

```
sheet_names <- excel_sheets(path)

read_excel_sheet <- function(sheet_name, path) {
  x <- read_excel(path = path, sheet = sheet_name)
}

Data <- lapply(sheet_names, read_excel_sheet, path = path)

str(Data)
```

This returns the following output:

```
List of 4
 $ :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   134 obs. of  80 variables:
```

So i know that i am reading the data in correctly into lists. Then i am trying this command to turn this list of data frames into time series:

```
Timeseries <- lapply(data, function(t) ts(t, start=c(2009, 1), end=c(2020, 2),frequency=12))
```

This returns the following error

```
Error in rep_len(data, nobs) : attempt to replicate non-vector
```

Does anyone know how to turn this list of data frames into a list of time series objects that I can pass through the seasonal package?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you want to convert each `data.frame` in the list into a separate `ts` object or if you want to bind all of them together.

1. **Independent `ts` objects in a list**

Just use `lapply()` to convert the `data.frame` to the desired class:

```
listofdf = list( A = data.frame( time = 1:10, y = rnorm(n_obs)),
                 B = data.frame( time = 11:20, y = rnorm(n_obs)),
                 C = data.frame( time = 21:30, y = rnorm(n_obs)) 
                 )

listofts = lapply( listofdf, as.ts )
```

2. **Bind them together**

In case you want to have a unique `ts` object, I would recommend you to using the great [**data.table**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/) package.

```
library(data.table)
listofdf = list( A = data.frame( time = 1:10, y = rnorm(n_obs)),
                 B = data.frame( time = 11:20, y = rnorm(n_obs)),
                 C = data.frame( time = 21:30, y = rnorm(n_obs)) 
                 )

listofdt = lapply( listofdf, setDT )
dt = rbindlist( listofdt )
final_ts = as.ts( dt )
```

Beware that you have to install the package with the usual `install.packages("data.table")`.